# Flask login_required for multiple pages

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have a homepage a create, delete and views page.  All these pages should be restricted to only logged in users.  The login functionality works for a single page only.  If I login sucessfully to the first page, lets say the home page and I click on the create page, I get redirected back to the login page.  I have to log back into the create page.  Same thing with any other page.  It only allows me to login to one page at a time.  How can I get my code to login once and allow me to browse to the home, create, delete and views page without having to relogin to each page?

```
main.py

    # Register Blueprints
    from .frontend.frontend import frontend
    from .login.login import login

    app.register_blueprint(frontend, url_prefix='/frontend')
    app.register_blueprint(login, url_prefix='/login')

    login_manager = LoginManager(app)
    login_manager.login_view = 'login.login_function'
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(id):
        return User.query.get(int(id))

    return app



frontend.py

  frontend = Blueprint('frontend', __name__)


  @frontend.route('/')
  @login_required
  def home_page():
      return render_template('frontend.html', html_name="home")


  @frontend.route('/create', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
  @login_required
  def create_key():
    pass


  @frontend.route('/delete', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
  @login_required
  def delete_key():
    pass


  @frontend.route('/view')
  @login_required
  def view_keys():
     pass
   

login.py

  login = Blueprint('login', __name__)


  @login.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
  def login_function():
      form = LoginForm()
      if form.validate_on_submit():
          username = form.username.data
          password = form.password.data

          # Query the db for user
          user = db.session.query(User).filter_by(username=username).first()
          if user and user.password == password:
              login_user(user)
              return redirect(url_for('frontend.home_page', username=user.username))
          else:
              flash('Invalid username or password', 'error')

      return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

Comment: Are you using flask-login? If so have you defined the @login_manager.user_loader? https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#how-it-works

You need to store the session information somewhere.